# value of select elements with "e.value" vs "e.options[e.selectedIndex].value"

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, selectedvalue, selectedindex

Given the HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementById('mySelect');
```

To get the value of the select I can use `e.value` and `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`.

I am aware that `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` will give me the selected value (1,2 or 3) and `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text` would give me test1, test2, test3 depending on which is selected.

Is it ok to use just `e.value`? was this a problem in old browsers?
which is more correct: `e.value` vs `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m91qatq/)

Comment: I can't see why not use the standard `e.value`. There're no browsers compatibility issues documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Both are correct. `e.value` takes less space which can be desirable from a bandwidth point of view.

Comment: @Rikard As you have suggested, it was an issue in very old browsers.  You could not use `.value` on the select itself, you had to get the selected option and take the value of that.

Comment: @JamesMontagne ok, interesting. Which browsers in IE-time-measures had problems? IE6- or less old like IE8-?

Comment: `value` is not an attribute of `select` according to MDN or W3C (http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select).  However, it seems to work in all browsers, so looks like it's safe to use.

Comment: @Rikard A quick google found that it didn't work at all in Netscape 4 and that IE6&7 had some oddities, though it wasn't fully broken.

Comment: @RickHitchcock interesting also. Hmmm... if W3C does not refer it feels strange this works. I would like to see a answer explaining my question.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: you need to learn about the difference between DOM properties and HTML attributes. Select elements [do indeed have a `.value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-value)

Comment: @MelanciaUK: The incompatibilities not being documented doesn't mean they don't exist :-) MDN isn't a very reliable ressource in that regard.

Comment: @Bergi, I stand corrected!  Nice to know select.value is safe to use.  But is that new as of HTML5?  All the discussion here says we should use `options ... selectedIndex`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: So many of us have been using selectedIndex for so many years - not because value wasn't a standard property, but because IE6 didn't support it.  It's safe to say IE6 isn't an issue anymore.  I have to wonder what other convolutions I use in my code, simply because IE6 didn't follow standards.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @RickHitchcock you are so right. IE not following standards has been "painfull".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HTMLSelectElement` interface includes the `value` attribute at least since Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Specification, from 1998.

However, like it is explained in [this w3c mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2000OctDec/0017.html), the problem was that HTML4.01 spec was vague:

> It's true that HTML4.01 doesn't explicitly specify a value attribute
>   for SELECT, but it does seem to be implied:
>
> - 'Menu' is a control type. ([HTML4.01 17.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1))
> - "Each control has both an initial value and a current value, both of
>     which are character strings" ([HTML4.01 17.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2))
> - And `SELECT` may have an `onchange` attribute which implies a value.
>     ([HTML4.01 17.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6))
>
> But there's no mention of what the value represents, nor of what the
>   initial or default values might be.
>
> However, checking in IE5 and Mozilla, the value of `SELECT` does indeed
>   return a string corresponding to the value of the currently selected
>   `OPTION`.
>
> (...) Probably wouldn't be a problem if HTML4.01 had been more explicit.

This was fixed in following definitions.

You can see it defined here:

- [`HTMLSelectElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980)'s [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-59351919) in [DOM Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/), W3C Recommendation, 01 October 1998

  > The current form control value.
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980)'s [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919) in [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), W3C Recommendation, 09 January 2003

  > The current form control value (i.e. the value of the currently selected option), if multiple options are selected this is the value of the first selected option.
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#htmlselectelement)'s [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#dom-select-value) in HTML5, W3C Candidate Recommendation

  > The `value` IDL attribute, on getting, must return the [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#concept-option-value) of the
  >   first [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#the-option-element) element in the [list of options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#concept-select-option-list) in [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#tree-order) that has its
  >   [selectedness](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#concept-option-selectedness) set to true, if any. If there isn't one, then it must
  >   return the empty string.

So I think it's safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

Some old (~2005) threads from the `comp.lang.javascript` newsgroup, as well as [their FAQ](http://jibbering.com/faq/#FAQ4_13) [[1]](http://pointedears.de/scripts/faq/cljs/#formControlAccess),  mention that `.value` access was not supported in [Netscape Navigator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) 4 (i.e. pre-2000), and some other mobile and desktop browsers that were considered "old" even at that time.

Conclusion (backed by @Oriol's DOM spec excerpts): It's totally safe to use today.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("pets");
    var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = 'The selected text is ' + text;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.